# Draggable split-view with image preview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

### [image: Layout Template]

I am trying to implement the above layout in my Android app.
Basically its two images filling the whole screen, but with a "slider" that is draggable and masks one image over the other. The labels are just some text relating to the image, and should also be masked over when dragged.

So far I haven't been able to see how best to do this using standard layouts, and have been thinking of how to implement this using Canvas.

Any help/tips on the most efficient way to implement this would be appreciated.

NOTE: The slider is supposed to work a lot like the one in the gallery image editor in stock android gallery - except that it stays in place after letting go.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using LibGDX and making a custom scene for everything.
Didn't find a way to do this using built-in layouts.